# PyQt5: Refresh GUI from (non QT) threads

Tags: python, qt, signals, pyqt5, python-multithreading

I have a PyQt5 application that is making use of different classes to collect data (from file system, psutil, serial link,...) and summarize it in a PyQt5 GUI, that is just another class run from my main python script.

All non-GUI classes were initialy non-Qt-aware at all and were doing their job fine (colelcting/updating internal lists of data on threads 
`from threading import Thread` and were pushing their updates directly to the GUI using callable on the mainwindow, with heavy 'setValue()': ahem...this (very) bad (I *knooOOoow*, I learned the hard way: window crashed while resizing)

Then I understood signals were the way to go and upgraded by non-Qt classes to the bare minimum: QObject. Then I could have a `dataReady = pyqtSignal(MyClass)` and a bit later:  `self.dataReady.emit(self.myclasses[idx])` and of course, then in the GUI (QMainWindow) class, I catch/connect this signal: `oneOfMyThreadedWorker.dataReady.connect(self.HandleThisMyClass)`

This is working great....or so great that I lost control of the GUI (not responding ?!) I take it it's soooo busy updating the GUI, it can't handle event anymore?

So....
How can I fix this? what am I doing wrong ? Is the QThread object the (only) way to go?

Comment: The famous MyClass actually contains a dozen of variable for the GUI to proceed/update, and there are ~20 instances of it (in a list/dict): shall I instead create a signal for each variable (ok, together with the instance index in second argument) ? is this more efficient in a 'divide and conquer' approach ?

Comment: While Qthreads with signal/slots is the official solution, you might want to look at a library I wrote for safely accessing Qt objects from Python threads: [qtutils](http://qtutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: Hey! Tank you, I am having a look at it... In the meantime, I also split my ugly 'object' passing into (soOOooo) many small signals to update fields individualy, and freezing disapeared. However, if I just want to have a real function (@pyqtSlot) for one signal (even few lines of code), it does freeze again, so I guess something is still not fresh here.

Comment: If you want help with that, please provide a [mcve] in the question.